# To return elements of a list from a function

Tags: python, list, function

I want to define a function that takes a list as its argument and then returns the elements in order.

For example:

```
def iterator(lis):
    for e in range(len(lis)):
        return lis[e]

l=input("Enter list elements:").split()
x=iterator(l)
print(x)
```

But this just returns the first value of the list as:

```
Enter list elements:12 23 34
12
```

How can I print all the values in successive lines?

Comment: You can use the built-in function `iter`.

Comment: use `print` instead of `return` and you get all values in successive lines

Comment: BTW: you could do this without `range(len())` using `for item in lis: print(item)`

Comment: BTW: because you have list with strings you can do `print( "\n".join(l) )`

Comment: Hello @Anshika Singh
I was wondering if you had time to check my answer.
If you find it useful please upvote it and / or mark it as final answer, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use yield in order to build a generator, [here's the official documentation about Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

What is a generator in Python?

> A Python generator is a function which returns a generator iterator
> (just an object we can iterate over) by calling yield. yield may be
> called with a value, in which case that value is treated as the
> "generated" value.

I also want to share an example, be sure to read the comments:

```
def iterator(lis):
    for e in range(len(lis)):
        yield lis[e]

l=input("Enter list elements:").split()

# A generator returns an Iterable so you should
# loop to print
for number in iterator(l):
    print(number)

# Or use list
result = list(iterator(l))
print(result)
```

**Output**
1
2
3
['1', '2', '3']

Comment: But this way, the list gets printed, and I want the elements in successive lines, returned from the function. @Pitto

Comment: Sorry but it is not 100x100 clear what do you want to obtain... If you just want to print the elements in successive lines why are you not using just a for loop?

Comment: How are you entering your number in the input box?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: I mean what are you writing when you request to user input? "12 32 23" and enter?

Comment: Yes, this is how I input the elements of the list.@Pitto

Comment: My code works exactly as you need...
Test it here: https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_NAls4YWps4_0.py

Comment: Hi @Anshika Singh, please consider upvoting my answer and / or selecting it as final answer if it was helpful for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `yield`, as `return` causes the function call to end immediately. But `yield` just produces another iterator; you still need to iterate over the result to print them all, rather than simply printing the iterator itself.

```
def iterator(lis):
    for e in range(len(lis)):
        yield lis[e]

...
for element in x:
    print(element)
```

Of course, you are pretty much just reimplementing the existing list iterator here; an equivalent definition would be

```
def iterator(lis):
    yield from lis
```

What you might want instead is to do something like

```
x = '\n'.join(l)
print(x)
```

which creates a string by iterating over `l` and joining the elements using `\n`. The resulting multiline string can then be printed.

Answer (score 1):

It will print only one element if you do `return`

```
def iterator(lis):
    for e in range(len(lis)):
        return lis[e]
l=input("Enter list elements:").split()
x=iterator(l)
for y in x: print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:
def iterator(list):
for e in range(len(list)):
a= list[e]
print(a)
l=a,b,c=input().split()
a=iterator(l)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[print(i) for i in input("Enter list elements:").split(" ")]
```

Comment: That's using a list comprehension for a side effect. That's an anti-pattern because it also builds a list of `None`

Comment: @roganjosh correct but if I'm not storing it anywhere, there's no memory loss in this situation and also doing my work easily.

Answer (score 0):

`return` causes the function to stop after it hits the statement. So your for loop only ever runs once.

You could use yield as mentioned in the other answers, but I really don't think you need a function in this situation. Because the function is just going to return the list that it took as an argument. What you should do is something like this:

```
i = input("Enter list elements: ").split()
for x in i:
   print(x)
```

It's that simple.

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but the question I'm trying to solve specifically demands the values be returned from a user defined function.

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you gave a little more context. Although what you asked for in your question was for a function that returned the value, you didn't specify _why_, and in the example you provided, it made much more sense to use a for loop. I still have a feeling that yield is still not the best option, but there's no way to know unless you edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
def iterator(lis):
    for e in range(len(lis)):
        print( lis[e])

l=input("Enter list elements:").split()
iterator(l)
```

if you want to do some operations for each item in the list, then you should accomodate those within the function.

Answer (score -1):

Use of print instead of return will give you the expected output..try it once